# two container pod creation in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

create a pod that runs two containers and ensure that the pod has shared volume that can be used by both containers to communicate with each other write an HTML file in one container and try accessing it from another container

can anyone tell me how to do it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell what have you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Example pod with multiple containers

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

Official document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Above example is using the empty dir so if you POD restart or Start again you will lose the data.

If you have any requirements to save the data i would suggest using the **PVC** instead of the empty dir.

i would recommend using the **NFS** if you can.

Comment: Do not recommend NFS, please. It's definitely the most common RWX volume type but it has heavy _heavy_ downsides. Not all workloads will function on NFS and most of those that do will see a heavy performance penalty.

Comment: I would suggest PVC to to share the data across the containers.

Comment: @coderanger got that...! Never used NFS in pod... thanks for pointing it out.